# how to solve No setter/field for 67903 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get a warning when I want to revert data from Firebase and SetValue in my ModelView class. I check all data in my database and ModelView Class. The key name of the ModelView String name is the same and also I make a setter method in the class. I don't understand where is the problem.

my ModelView Class code:

```
public class PostGeter {
    private String body;
    private String date;
    private String id;
    private String image;
    private String reaction;
    private String status;
    private String title;
    private String userId;

    public PostGeter() {}

    public PostGeter(String body, String date, String id, String image, String reaction, String status, String title, String userId) {
        this.body = body;
        this.date = date;
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.reaction = reaction;
        this.status = status;
        this.title = title;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setReaction(String reaction) {
        this.reaction = reaction;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getReaction() {
        return reaction;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
```

my adapter class:

```
public class postAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<postAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<PostGeter> list;

    public postAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PostGeter> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public postAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_content_view, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull postAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PostGeter geter = list.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(geter.getTitle());
        holder.content.setText(geter.getBody());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView img; TextView title,content;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImageView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_view_title);
            content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_view_content);
        }
    }
}
```

my firebase Data call method:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.postView;
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter customAdapter = new postAdapter(getContext(), list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        reference = database.getReference().child("posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()){
                            System.out.println(data);
                            PostGeter msg = ds.getValue(PostGeter.class);
                            list.add( msg);

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw error.toException();

            }
        });
```

my log:

```
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=59KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/FA: Application going to the background
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = 10843, value = {body=fasiaufsuie, title=ddddj} }
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 10843 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 67903 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = 67903, value = {date=06.03.2023, image=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hello-writer-2db52.appspot.com/o/posts%2FuserId%2F67903?alt=media&token=5bc42574-fe50-424a-8e74-af7aae7e33d0, reaction=0, id=67903, body=jgugjvvhv, title=vhhvvhuv, userId=user, status=approved} }
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 10843 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 67903 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = 67903, value = {date=06.03.2023, image=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hello-writer-2db52.appspot.com/o/posts%2FuserId%2F67903?alt=media&token=5bc42574-fe50-424a-8e74-af7aae7e33d0, reaction=0, id=67903, body=jgugjvvhv, title=vhhvvhuv, userId=user, status=approved} }
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 67903 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter
```

I want to show the data in recyclerView. My database JSON link is here:

[My database json](https://hello-writer-2db52-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code.

Comment: I want to get data from firebase and set those data in modelView class, and then that will be show in RecyclerView in android app

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `PostGeter` class.

Comment: first code is for my PostGeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following warning:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 67903 found on class com.hello.writer.postAdapter.PostGeter

Because you trying to convert a key into an object of type `PostGeter` using the following line of code:

```
PostGeter msg = ds.getValue(PostGeter.class);
```

To solve this, you have to use the right `DataSnapshot` object. So please change the above line of code into:

```
PostGeter msg = data.getValue(PostGeter.class);
//
```

Comment: Sorry to say that its not working.

Comment: data not going to the Modelview class what I can do?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't provide enough information so I can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?